# How to create bins for a dataframe column if the range is given

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
data = {'Age':[18, 22,29,32,35,38,42,54,47]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

This is an example data frame that I want to play with

```
pd.cut(df['Age'],bins=5)
```

If I do this, I get the output as:

```
0    (17.964, 25.2]
1    (17.964, 25.2]
2      (25.2, 32.4]
3      (25.2, 32.4]
4      (32.4, 39.6]
5      (32.4, 39.6]
6      (39.6, 46.8]
7      (46.8, 54.0]
8      (46.8, 54.0]
```

Here's the twist: Let's say the age columns can take values between 18 to 58(the range of the column) and I want the bins(or the output) as:

```
0    (18.0, 26.0]
1    (18.0, 26.0]
2    (26.0, 34.0]
3    (26.0, 34.0]
4    (34.0, 42.0]
5    (34.0, 42.0]
6    (34.0, 42.0]
7    (50.0, 58.0]
8    (42.0, 50.0]
```

How can I do that? because 'cut' takes the values which are in the column. I got the desired result by doing it manually but if the values of bins were say 100 - how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an array to `bins`:

```
pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=np.linspace(18, 58, 100), include_lowest=True)
```

Output:

```
0    (17.999, 18.404]
1     (21.636, 22.04]
2    (28.909, 29.313]
3    (31.737, 32.141]
4     (34.97, 35.374]
5    (37.798, 38.202]
6    (41.838, 42.242]
7     (53.96, 54.364]
8    (46.687, 47.091]
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass a sequence of the intervals you want to the `bins=` argument.

For example:

```
pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=[18,26,34,42,58], right=False)
```

Note: I passed `right=False`, as I assumed that you wanted the bins left-inclusive. For more information read the [pandas.cut docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

Output:

```
0    [18, 26)
1    [18, 26)
2    [26, 34)
3    [26, 34)
4    [34, 42)
5    [34, 42)
6    [42, 58)
7    [42, 58)
8    [42, 58)
Name: Age, dtype: category
Categories (4, interval[int64]): [[18, 26) < [26, 34) < [34, 42) < [42, 58)]
```

Comment: What if I want to make 100 bins? Is there any way to do it by not doing it manually?

Comment: The sequence doesn't have to be created manually you could use all sorts of functions to derive it eg `np.linspace` or `np.arange`